# Braintree js drop in - unexpected token

Tags: javascript, braintree

Setting up Braintree drop in UI in my Symfony 4 app, rendering form in twig template.

```
<script>
      var form = document.querySelector('#payment-form');

      braintree.dropin.create({
        authorization: {{ braintree_client_token }},
        selector: '#bt-dropin',
        paypal: {
          flow: 'vault'
        }
      }, function (createErr, instance) {
        if (createErr) {
          console.log('Create Error', createErr);
          return;
        }
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
            if (err) {
              console.log('Request Payment Method Error', err);
              return;
            }
            // Add the nonce to the form and submit
            document.querySelector('#nonce').value = payload.nonce;
            form.submit();
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Error in console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

Seems to be taking exception with comma after the line
    authorization: {{ braintree_client_token }},

yet I remove that and get similar error without the comma:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Is there a syntax issue or something else? I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Where it says `{{ braintree_client_token }}` is where you're supposed to put your Braintree public API key as a string. So that line should be:

```
authorization: "your key goes here",
```